# Node js + angular 1.6 routing

Tags: node.js, angularjs

Все запросы направлены на главную страницу,

```
app.use('*', index);
```

как исключить из этого АПИ?

```
app.get('/api/news', newsController.all);
```

так как логично что по даному запросу возвращает html код страницы.

Comment: Для АПИ можно завести поддомен.

Comment: да но это както не очень, или правильно делать АПИ на поддомене??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разместить

```
app.use('*', ...);
```

в самом конце middleware. При этом шаблон ангуляра вынести в pug или подключить движок html

```
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

После чего шаблон вывести через render

````
app.use('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('```Фаил Шаблона```')
});
````

P.S. Также рекомендую API вынести в модуль роутер.